# Is this a good design for a variable power supply?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, linear-regulator

Alright, so I've been studying designs and I saw designs that are far more sophisticated that's why I tried making my own design. I'm not an used to these kind of stuffs yet since we've just began studying circuits that's why I wanna ask if this kind of design works.

[image: My Design]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this circuit? Specifics help us a lot.

Comment: I want to ask the disadvantages of this circuit design compared to the other variable power supply circuit designs. I tried making a design that needs fewer components.

Comment: Even knowing there is a major disadvantage with this circuit, it'll be worth to build it on a bread board and see for yourself how well it conforms to your expectation. No better way to learn electronics than to experiment and try to understand what happens and how to improve it.

Comment: It is a reasonable variable *voltage* supply, but it has very bad voltage regulation under varying currents. If that was not your goal it is OK.

Comment: I tried virtually simulating it (Since that's all I can do for testing it) and it works fine for me. I just became curious of why I never saw this design anywhere in the internet.

Comment: What exactly do you intend "Alright, so" to convey at the beginning of the first sentence?  It seems like content-free time-wasting fluff from a small mind that does things without actually thinking about them.  Then there is "wanna".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a variable resistor to alter the output voltage - this makes it a bad design especially if you wish to draw anything above a few milli amps from the circuit. Use an adjustable voltage regulator is my advice.

The variable resistor output voltage is fine if you don't load the output but as soon as you start to take current significant volt drops appear and you lose your output voltage accuracy. Also, variable resistors are not regarded as power devices so you can easily burn one out on even a few milli amps of load.

Comment: I see. So that's why I never saw a design like this anywhere. I'll read about adjustable voltage regulator and remake the whole circuit. Thank you.

Comment: @JRA If you are satisfied with this answer please feel free to formally accept it by pressing the button below the up/down arrows to the left of my answer text.

Answer (score 0):

The 78xx series regulators are not really meant to be used as variable voltages sources. This is why they have so many numerical variations. As some have mentioned your circuit with the output from the variable resistor would suffer from low regulation due to a limited current condition.  Though if a regulator is already available in a circuit the method you show with a variable resistor is sometimes used when only an extremely low current is required, (such as a reference voltage).

The 78xx series parts can be made into a moderately good variable regulator by adjusting the voltage seen at the GND pin.  See an example of this here: http://www.pcsilencioso.com/cpemma/reg.html

A better choice would be to use a similar part that is designed to be used as a variable voltage regulator. It uses about the same adjustment methods as the example above. Try looking up an LM317.  Here is one example: http://www.circuitstoday.com/few-lm317-voltage-regulator-circuits